# How to make an object reactivated in vuejs2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

Hello everyone first of all, thanks for your answers and opinions, I find the following problem I want to generate forms dynamically, I have a view which receives an object, this object is a variant that is, it can have different values I have managed to show the fields but I can't make it reactive when user enters data. I share part of the code of the view.

```
<template>
 <q-card-section v-for="(column, key, index) in tableColumns" :key="index" >
    <div class="row q-col-gutter-sm">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <q-input square outlined :label="key" :value="column" />
        </div>
    </div>
</q-card-section>
</template>
```

In the script tag I have the object like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CreateField',
  data() {
    return {
      tableName: '',
      tableColumns: {
        nombre: '',
        apellidos: '',
        edad: null
      }
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I am looking for that when entering a data in the inputs this is reflected in tableColumns so that the object is reactive, any help or guidance is well received, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated one-way binding `:value="column"` which means only to show a value and not to save its changes back to `column`.
Try to use the `v-model` directive:

```html
<q-input square outlined :label="key" v-model="tableColumns[index]" />
```

P.S. and use `index` as a key only if your array is not modified in terms of its length (i.e. adding/removing items). Otherwise, it's better to use objects isread of strings with unique identifier field values among other fields.

Comment: Hello @Anatoly thanks for your answer, it is correct what you mention what happens is that if I specify v-model = "column" it marks me the following error 'v-model' directives cannot update the iteration variable 'column' itself, but the form of consider the solution with indexes is good I will try.

Comment: Changed in the answer